# Mod_rewrite (htaccess) QSA and removing charactes from appended query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, qsa

I've been struggling with some htaccess redirects. I just spent some time reading and searching and couldn't get a solution that works with my scenario.

I'm in the process of making the 301 redirect for an old website (ASP) to a new one (Wordpress). The old pages has parameters query which I need to process but also remove 'http://' string from it to get redirect to work.

Example URL (old) to redirect looks like:

```
http://www.domain.org/index.asp?documentID=2410&utm_source=IT+Travel+Reminder&utm_medium=Informz%2FnetFORUM&utm_campaign=IT%2FTravel+Reminder%2FMonthly+Monthly+Travel+Reminder&zbrandid=4050&zidType=CH&zid=28841368&zsubscriberId=1036792259&zbdom=http://my.informz.net
```

redirected to:

```
http://www.domain.org/permalink-2410/?qs=true&utm_source=IT+Travel+Reminder&utm_medium=Informz%2FnetFORUM&utm_campaign=IT%2FTravel+Reminder%2FMonthly+Monthly+Travel+Reminder&zbrandid=4050&zidType=CH&zid=28841368&zsubscriberId=1036792259&zbdom=my.informz.net
```

and .htaccess code to redirect it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^documentid=2410(&.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.asp(.*):(.*)$  http://www.domain.org/permalink/?qs=true%1%2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

but somehow is not working as I have expected when

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^documentid=2410(&.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.asp$ http://www.domain.org/permalink/?qs=true%1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

works fine when I will remove `http://` or `:` from a query string.

Where do I have made mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: What should be redirected URL for above asp URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^documentid=(\d+)(&.+?)http://(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.asp$ http://www.domain.org/permalink-%1/?qs=true%2%3 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to clear browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Somehow is not working for whole `RewriteCond` - works fine for `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^documentid=(\d+)` only

Comment: I have tested this rule on my Apache and it worked fine. Make sure this is first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line. URL you must enter to test should be: `http://www.domain.org/index.asp?documentID=2410&utm_source=IT+Travel+Reminder&utm_medium=Informz%2FnetFORUM&utm_campaign=IT%2FTravel+Reminder%2FMonthly+Monthly+Travel+Reminder&zbrandid=4050&zidType=CH&zid=28841368&zsubscriberId=1036792259&zbdom=http://my.informz.net`

Comment: I have `RewriteEngine On` and I have tested that rule on two different servers running cPanel - both are not able to get pass that condition

Comment: It looks like WP htaccess rules (some kind of additional) create issues with your solution which BTW works fine on a clean htaccess file. Will dig deeper how to marry it with existing one. Thanks!